# Hardware requirements for .net Application in Production server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hardware, server-hardware

I have developed my ASP.net application with SQL Server 2005 which as installed version
of .net Framework 2.0.

Please some one suggest what are the hardware requirements (windows server) to host in Production server and its configuration
to host the application.

The total number of users around 10,000 per second

around 10,000 requests per second.

Comment: In order to get a good answer, you may want to add some more details.  Are SQL and IIS running on the same hardware?  Is it a write-intensive environment (like stock trades) or is everyone just reading (like news sites)?  Have you benchmarked it on small hardware to see how much load it supports?

Answer (score 1):

10k requests per second is pretty hardcore, unless they're very light requests you're going to need multiple servers clustered. Speak to your hardware vendor of choice in detail about your requirements, it's not possible for anyone to help out much more without spending a lot more time with you understanding the requirements better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tpc.org/ might give you guidelines on what hardware can handle your needs.  Be sure to examine their criteria for a transaction and see if it matches up to yours.

http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/results/tpcc_results.asp?orderby=dbms gives a listing by database vendor.

You give little information, but one request per second from each user seems a little too often.